# How can I manage NSMutableArray memory

Tags: android, ios, contacts, voip

I am developing contacts based application on iOS.

Basically I used NSMutableArray for people management.

Here is my code.

This code will be occur crash sometimes.

if there is no crash then I can show *allPeople* count on debug window.

When I got crash then I can see only *allPeople*  memory address.

It seems that *allPeople* already has been released.

What is my mistake?

Thank you.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *allPeople_;

    - (void) C {


     ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(addressbookRef, ^(bool granted, CFErrorRef error) {
                if (!granted) {
                    return;
                }                              

 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
            [self A];
            [self B];
        });
    }
- (void)A {

@autoreleasepool {

        NSMutableArray *people = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:_allPeople_];
        //do something

        [arrayLock lock];
        _allPeople_ = people;
        [arrayLock unlock];
    }
}

- (void)B {

        //Here is crash location.            
        NSMutableArray *people = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:_allPeople_];
        //do something

        [arrayLock lock];
        _allPeople_ = people;
        [arrayLock unlock];
}
```

Here is crash log.

```
Fatal Exception: NSRangeException
*** -[__NSArrayM getObjects:range:]: range {0, 3009} extends beyond bounds for empty array

Fatal Exception: NSRangeException
0  CoreFoundation                 0x18d57afe0 __exceptionPreprocess
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x18bfdc538 objc_exception_throw
2  CoreFoundation                 0x18d45d13c -[__NSArrayM getObjects:range:]
3  CoreFoundation                 0x18d45cc80 -[NSArray initWithArray:range:copyItems:]
4  CoreFoundation                 0x18d45cb74 +[NSArray arrayWithArray:]
5  App                           0x1001f92b4 -[AddressCollector C]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I think that you posted answer already:
[__NSArrayM getObjects:range:]: range {0, 3009} extends beyond bounds for empty array

You are trying to access empty array with range that is well beyond it :). Most likely memory is managed already for you with ARC.

Suggestions:

- don't use lock, unlock if you are using this code on main thread
  only. It is useless.
- if you use multiple threads (you are not showing
  it with your code, nor comment) use property that is atomic. and you
  don't need lock, unlock (you have nonatomic)
- use autoreleasepool only
  when your are creating many short-lived objects. (for example many
  strings with NSString). Remember, with multithreading you need to
  protect data.
- for background processing it is beneficial to move update into main thread like this:
  `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                      self._allPeople_ = processedAllPeople;
  //update UI
                                  });`

  You don't need to sync as all updates will be on the same thread. UI can be updated only on main thread.
- make a copy of data if your UI is using that array during update. You need deep copy.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I call C function on multi background thread.

Comment: Don't worry about low performance, you are just assigning new array there and I guess that processing is not happening often. You are not saving nanoseconds in right place ;)

Comment: Also, if you use that dispach_async technique you don't need to sync at all. Just make sure you have deep copy of data you are processing. It would be bad if you are modifying data that are consumed by UI.

Comment: would be good if you posted the code example with that background processing. Inside that function, lets say update each name to have name+number2. Ex: James -> James2. I guess you have some problem there.

Comment: ok, so first run, self._allPeople_ is nil. You need to initialize it. At start of C: if (!self._allPeople_) { self._allPeople_ = [NSMutableArray array]; }

Comment: I need this code on the first run? self._allPeople_ = [NSMutableArray array]; how about this code? _allPeople_ = [people copy];

Comment: yes, because self._allPeople_ is nil, it is not empty array.

Comment: allPeople = [people copy] -> if allPeople is mutable array, than assigning a copy will make it non-mutable or normal array and trying to modify it will raise exception. There is a mutableCopy but that is not what you need. If property is nil, making a copy from nil is again nil.

Comment: totally, I have to use atomic for _allPeople_  and use  self._allPeople_ = [NSMutableArray array];, right? and then I need this code? allPeople = [people copy];

Comment: yes. And you can drop atomic if you use this: dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                    self._allPeople_ = processedAllPeople;
                                }); Remember that at that point, when you update that array, you also need to update UI. So you will need to call reload data on tableview or collection view.

Comment: Thank you for your help, really Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try to make a copy of the array: `_allPeople_ = [people copy];`

I am not sure if the autoreleasepool is necessary, memory is automatically managed by the OS.

Instead of making a lock, you can call

```
@synchronized(_allPeople_) {

}
```

Comment: I dont see where you fill your property. In the code you posted, it seems always empty. Is it externally filled? Can you post more code? Maybe the problem is not in this code but in the places that you call C or set the property.

Comment: maybe I need this code. _allPeople_ = [people copy]

Comment: no, that copy is creating NSArray, that is not mutable.

Comment: Well instead of a simple copy, make a mutable copy `[people mutableCopy]`

Comment: if I use mutableCopy then I have problem. as you can see, I have to manage about 4000~5000 contacts, it will be occur memory issue, right?

Comment: Not necessarily. ARC will release memory when needed. I dont get your code. The property is nil because it is not initialized in any place, then your are creating a new array of this property and again storing this new array in the property. No change is made. Why this?

Comment: Thank you for your help, really Thank you